# Opening and closing an iframe document within `onload`

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, document

Would there be any sort of issue or specification incompatibility caused by calling

```js
 // assume iframe.contentWindow was checked beforehand and is defined
 iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
 iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

within the iframe `onload` function?

e.g.

```js
iframe.onload = () => {
 // ...
 // assume iframe.contentWindow was checked beforehand and is defined 
 iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
 iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}
```

The background to this is that when creating a friendly iframe, I want to get a reference to the iframe window and do certain operations with no / minimal writing to the iframe beforehand using `document.write()` and without having to use `setTimeout` (see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978325 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=961428 for why `setTimeout` would be needed)

The issue is that without calling `open` or when calling it prior to the `onload` function, the iframe `location` is set to `about:blank` (see https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#opening-the-input-stream step 13). This can also be solved by adding a `setTimeout` after opening the document (outside of `onload`) at the cost of performance, which I would like to avoid.

The solution involving calling `open` and `close` within the `onload` function works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but JSDom considers the `contentDocument` to be `null` and the iframe itself to have no children when using this method (after manually simulating a call to `onload`, which is a separate issue, but might be related to the behavior)

Comment: Why not just load a pre-defined document to the iframe, and then modify it from the main window with normal document manipulation methods?

Comment: @Teemu as in using `srcdoc` or as in using a src from the same domain? In my usecase the iframe must have the the same `location` as the parent (`srcdoc` also has some issues in that regard), and using a src from the same domain also wouldn't work as this is a third party script, I don't control the domain